# C random number generator

Tags: c

I have written the following code to generate random numbers in C.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int iseed = (unsigned int)time(NULL);
    srand (iseed);

    /* Generate random number*/
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        printf ("Random[%d]= %u\n", i, rand ());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output gives me a 10 digit random number, how can I change the number of digits printed in the output?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Are you asking how to make rand return a bigger number, how to make the printf statement show more/less digits?

Comment: Also, RAND_MAX is typically 32767 on many systems. So your code may only be a 5 digit number at best depending on where it's compiled.

Comment: Your code passes an `int` off for an `unsigned int`. A good compiler should have warned you about that; make sure you've set up your build environment correctly. StackOverflow generally frowns upon questions that weren't tested with maximal warning levels.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to make the printf statement show less digits.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with `rand()`? Please put a bit more effort in formulating your question. Did you look up the documentation of your platform for `printf`? What did it say?

Comment: Your question is very much unclear! do you want to truncate the result? if so read printf documentation as was suggested before, do you want do get a random result in some range less then MAX_INT, then you need to use wisely modulo operator, remember that a distribution of a random numbers is not uniform, if you want to increase your range above MAX_INT, use bit shifting together with applying rand on each batch of bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rand()` gives you a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, which may be a large number.

If you want to get a uniform sample in the range `[0, N)`, you need to divide the range into regions:

```
int my_max = (RAND_MAX / N) * N;

int result;

while ((result = rand()) >= my_max) { } // #1

return result % N;
```

The condition on line `#1` should be met only very rarely, but we need to re-roll in the case where the result doesn't lie inside a range that is a multiple of `N` to avoid bias against high results.